# Notification Codes

Tags: android, notifications

I learnt these codes online, and I am working on the notification after registering an account. There were no errors and the app runs fine, except that no notifications appear after I clicked the Register button. I have edited the codes as shown, it still does not work.please advice.

```
public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {
public static final String channelID = "channelID";
public static final String channelName = "channelNAME";
public static final String channelDescrip = "channelDescrip";
NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager;



DatabaseHelper myDb;
EditText editEmail,editUsername,editPassword,editCfmpw ;
Button btnRegister;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
    myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    editEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email_field);
    editUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username_field);
    editPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password_field);
    btnRegister = (Button)findViewById(R.id.register_btn);
    editCfmpw = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.cfm_pw_field);
    notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);


}

private void createNotificationChannel() {
    // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
    // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = channelName;
        String description = channelDescrip;
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelID, name,
                importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);
        // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
        // or other notification behaviors after this
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [this](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification#java)

notifications should have priority

```
.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
```

And on 8+ android you should create Notification Channel

```
private void createNotificationChannel() {
    // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
    // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = getString(R.string.channel_name);
        String description = getString(R.string.channel_description);
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, 
            importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);
        // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
        // or other notification behaviors after this
        NotificationManager notificationManager = 
            getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am having errors with the channel_name,channel_description and CHANNEL_ID. And do I just put them under my onclick function?

Comment: do i have to call any method in my onclick?